# How to create a event in Microsoft Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can I create an event that fires ever 5 minutes in SQL-Server? I have been working with SQL in different forms for a couple of years but have never had to create a trigger. And believe it or not I only have currently mySQL books and that is not working exactly as I thought that it would.

I think that the code below is close but I am not certain as to were it is off.

**Code:**

```
   create event oneTimeEvent
   on database SQLtestdatabase
   for
   insert into table1(Value) 
               values ('TestB');
   end
```

Is it possible that someone could show an example of this. Even if it is just a screen shot or the SQL statement.

Comment: There is no "Server 2010" - neither a *Windows Server 2010* nor a *SQL Server 2010* - so what exactly do you refer to?

Comment: A trigger is an event - A customer walked into a store. You are not describing an event. You are describing a recurring activity - the delivery truck comes Tuesday's at 10:00. For this, we use a scheduler. Windows ships with a native scheduler. SQL Server has one as well (SQL Agent). There are also many commercial products

Comment: You need to schedule a job in SQL Agent

Comment: MySQL's dialect of SQL is not compatible with SQL Server's dialect. You have no need to spend money on books, it's all on-line. [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn198336.aspx)

Comment: The two are different dialects but you can sometimes make them work by only changing a few key words. There is a good quick reference book that I purchased on my kindle on Amazon for a couple of dollars.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you have access to SQL Management Studio, you need to go into the SQL Server Agent and set you job up there.  You can set the frequency for as often as you'd like.

As far as the steps in the job itself, I would advise saving a package out of Visual Studio.  So you create your job, save it to the server, and the the Agent to run that job whenever you specify.

Comment: I vote up for your ans, but here you have forget to mention the software version. SQL Server Agent is only available in SSMS professional version, you will not find this in Express edition.